# Hamburger toggle is not working on mobile

Tags: html, css

I made a hamburger toggle that is supposed to transform. On my laptop it shows perfectly but on my mobile nothing is done to it. It is just a checkbox on the left side. None of the styles were applied to it. I have media queries but none apply to this. It is bootstrap but I made a custom toggler.

```
#custom-toggler {
      border: none;
      float: right;
      margin: 25px 15px 0 0

    }

    #custom-toggler input{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
  left: 5px;
  float: right;

  cursor: pointer;

  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */

  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#custom-toggler input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: white;
}

#custom-toggler span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#custom-toggler span:last-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

#custom-toggler input:checked ~ span:last-child
{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

#custom-toggler input:checked ~ span:nth-child(2n-1)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

    #custom-toggler span {
      display: block;
      width: 33px;
      height: 4px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      position: relative;
      background: #cdcdcd;
      border-radius: 3px;
      z-index: 1;


      transform-origin: 4px 0px;

      transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
                  background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
                  opacity 0.55s 

    }

    <nav class="small-nav navbar-light fixed-top ">
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="index.html"><img id='logo'  
  src="../image/TreysCode-logo1.png"></a>
   <div id='custom-toggler'>


  <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
  target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
   controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
   label="Toggle navigation"/>
  <span ></span>
  <span ></span>
  <span ></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: This code works just fine, could you please provide runable code to reproduce? There can be something overlaping in your html, we cant help you with this little information.

Comment: what information would you need?

Comment: I am not sure what would cause it to work perfectly on laptops or larger screens then on my mobile it doesn't work at all

Comment: Could it be a mobile browser issue?

Comment: What phone are you using, what browser, can you provide your html with css?

Comment: Iphone x, Safari. The html code for the hamburger is on the bottom of the post.

Comment: I meant for the whole page, btw do you know you were missing } in the code you pasted

Comment: Okay, chrome works fine on mobile. How would I fix it for safari? Sorry I am new to this. I wasn't sure how to format the question..

Comment: https://codepen.io/Gibonek/pen/gOOgddJ can you try to open this on your phone?

Comment: I opened the link, what am I supposed to be doing? There is nothing on the result tab. Sorry again, new to this.

Comment: @Roughcaster Have you tried adding the `-webkit-` prefix for Safari? A lot of styles like `transform` and `transition` don't work on Safari without them.

Comment: well you were supose to see your hamburger, I run it on safari, iphone 11

Comment: Would i put the -webkit- in each css {} that includes a transform/transition?

Comment: Yeah there is nothing there for me

Comment: not even empty icon in top left corner?

Comment: On my phone its just a blank, white box.

Comment: cdpn.io’s server IP address could not be found. Thats what I get for result on my macbook

Comment: Iam sorry, no idea whats wrong then, the code you provided is just fine, rule `#custom-toggler span` was missing `}` at the end but I belive that was error in copy/paste

Comment: It seems like its what @AlexG was saying. Safari needs the webkit to use the transformations. Since it works fine on my phone using chrome. Know where I would put the webkit?

Comment: "none of the css is working on that element in safari"  -  Then Safari might override your code on the input, you stated you're using a MacBook. Try activating the developer tools in Safari and inspect the element. Safari on Desktop is also able to connect to your iPhone/iPad, try inspecting your code that way.

Answer (score 0):

## Missing Vendor prefixes

Safari is one of those Browsers which still requires the `-webkit-*` prefix on most newer Styles.

Just turn every of the following

```
transform: ...;
transform-origin: ...;
transition: ...,
            transform ...;
```

into

```
-webkit-transform: ...;
transform: ...;
-webkit-transform-origin: ...;
transform-origin: ...;
-webkit-transition: ...,
            -webkit-transform ...,
            transform ...;
transition: ...,
            -webkit-transform ...,
            transform ...;
```

If a browser sees the `-webkit-*` it will use it if it can, if not they get simply ignored and the next (non-prefixed) Style gets used.

Comment: The only thing is none of the css is working on that element in safari. not just the animation. The color and location is also not working when using safari.

Comment: forgot to tag you